# Experience with using google closure library in AIR?

Tags: air, google-closure

I would like to try closure library in an AIR application. Will be using objects like goog.editor, goog.events and goog.dom.

In an older book I'm reading about google closure it says it's using eval in some functions. I haven't tried using uncompiled code in AIR yet but suspect it would not work because eval isn't allowed in privileged code. Plan to compile the code to be used in the AIR application.

The application would be made of a html page with code using some AIR specific things like save as and copy to clipboard. It will not have any ActionScript or swf files.

Has anyone tried using closure library in AIR applications? If so are there things to look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Closure library uses eval in it's JSON parser, the JsonDataSource, and the ModuleLoader but otherwise does not (AFAIK) use eval in any core libraries for standard components. As long as you avoid those cases I would not expect that to be an issue, but I'm not familiar with how AIR restricts usage of that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try working on this later this week and post my findings.

Comment: I can confirm that uncompiled code works, the JSON parser probably won't but using goog.dom and goog.events loads the libraries in AIR and works fine. I will post problems when and if I have them.